# How to send gpg-encrypted emails with attachments using PHP?

Tags: php, email, attachment, gnupg

I am looking for an easy way in PHP to send GPG encrypted emails with attachments.

I understand the individual pieces on how to send emails, how to use gpg command line and how MIME works. But I am interested in existing libraries. So that I don't re-invent the wheel on a low level.

The encrypted emails will be reading using Thunderbird with Enigmail.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [GnuPG extension](http://www.php.net/gnupg), failing that you're best off using `exec()` and friends to invoke the regular gpg binaries.  There's a decent [Zend article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265) showing hints for the latter approach

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote, I am aware of how to invoke gpg to encrypt files. I am looking for a solution that puts the various error prone parts together to send encrypted emails with attachments. I could do that myself, but I think other have had the same problem.

Comment: That Zend article link is now broken, and it doesn't appear to be in the wayback machine either.

Answer (score 0):

There is ongoing work at PEAR to accomplish this; see https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=20938

Answer (score 0):

You may try php-gpg from https://github.com/jasonhinkle/php-gpg

It supports the encryption using a public key.